# How do I remove an image used in the background?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[blender file](http://aff.mach1.online/sbd.blend)

I've been working with a template that I downloaded, and was trying to remove the image that is in the background.  I went into the properties pane, ( n ) then selected the image, and selected remove pack. Then deleted what was written in the field, the image then came up blank.

I am trying to do a transparent background.. so I then set it to RBGA and set under film to "transparent"

The rendered and the layer with the background image is still showing up...

Any advice on how to remove that layer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot things like this without the blend file. Can you upload it?

Comment: sure give me a moment ill have it uploaded

Comment: Images used in the background in the 3d viewport are not rendered, so changing anything there would have no effect. It is likely that the image is either used as part of the world background in the scene,  or is being used on an image node on the compositor. Please [edit] your question and add images that show those settings.

Comment: @Aoradon ok uploaded

Comment: If you wish to remove the image altogether from this file, you can find it in the Outliner, "Blender File" mode, find this particular image, right click, and select delete.  It will be gone from this file, and all links will break.  You might see a pink object if any object is using that image.  If you wish to use it now as the template, make sure you save it.

Answer (score -4):

I'd recommend saving the file as an image and using something like Photoshop or Pixlr to remove the background.